# Cannot trigger dispatches from GitHub API

Tags: github, github-api, github-actions

I want to trigger a GitHub Actions workflow manually. Through [the docs](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#create-a-repository-dispatch-event) I found out I can do so through a [repository dispatch event](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/event-payloads/#repository_dispatch).

The problem is that when I hit the API at the `/dispatches` endpoint, I get the following error:

```
{
    "message": "Not Found",
    "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#create-a-repository-dispatch-event"
}
```

I have write access to the repo. I generated myself an access token.

Is the dispatches functionality enabled by default or do I need to "enable" it somehow, so the the `/dispatches` endpoint becomes available? Either I didn't look well enough, or this is not described in the docs.

I don't know if it makes a difference, but the repo is owned by an organization, not by an individual user.

Comment: It's enabled by default and works just fine with organization repo. Try with `Content-Type: application/json` header?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem turned out to be very basic. I was sending the `Authorization` header with `Bearer` prefix, before the actual token, whereas I was supposed to send it with `token` prefix.

Needless to say, the returned error message is quite misleading.

Comment: Thank you for sharing, would you mind providing the exact headers you sent (minus the token itself of course!)?

Comment: @ben.hamelin, I'm sorry, but I'm not part of the organization where I used that anymore, so I don't have access to the Postman account where I had this request. :)

Comment: no worries, I figured it out. The Authorization header was in the format `token ACCESS_TOKEN` - Also the token needs the `admin:repo_hook` write permission  as seen here: https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token

Comment: For me, the problem was caused by the user account that the token belonged to did not have write access to the repository. When that was resolved, the curl example from the documentation worked fine, even with `Bearer <token>`.

Comment: I took more time to find what is the reason. It is because of permission and some parameters. I already made a demo to save time.
It includes how to call a job in GitHub action via bashshell or python code and how to grant permissions for the token that is used to call API.
https://github.com/lamhaison/template-github-action

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error - followed the doc to the letter all the headers were set, token had correct privileges... but still had a 404

the doc says "you can replace workflow_id by the name of the file". But that didn't work.

I ended doing a post request to `{{baseUrl}}/repos/{{owner}}/{{repo}}/actions/workflows` and grabbed the id from there.

from that point, the call to `{{baseUrl}}/repos/{{owner}}/{{repo}}/actions/workflows/{{workflowId}}/dispatches` worked