# Getting "not found" after authenticating when trying to initiate GitHub workflow via REST

Tags: github, github-actions

I am trying to trigger the `workflow_dispatch` action for a GitHub workflow via REST but I am getting a "not found" error.

My question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63042765/cannot-trigger-dispatches-from-github-api) but the difference is that I am still getting the "not found" error even though the header indicates I am authenticated (the rate limit has increased to 5,000).

Here's my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/actions#create-a-workflow-dispatch-event

OWNER='myGithubOrganization'
REPO='myRepo'
WORKFLOW_ID='main.yml'
POST_URL="https://api.github.com/repos/$OWNER/$REPO/actions/workflows/$WORKFLOW_ID/dispatches"

echo "Calling $POST_URL"

GITHUB_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN=$(echo "$PLATFORM_VARIABLES" | base64 --decode | jq '.GITHUB_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN' --raw-output)

# -i to include headers.

curl \
  -i \
  -X POST \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
  -H "Authorization: token $GITHUB_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN" \
   $POST_URL \
  -d '{"ref":"ref"}'
```

In the headers, I see the rate limit has increased to 5,000, so I know I am logged in.

The personal access token has the following permissions:

- repo
- workflow
- admin:org_hook

The personal access token is for a machine user.

In the repo settings, under "Collaborators and teams", the machine user account has the "Read" role.

What more do I need to do to trigger the workflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The machine user needs to have `write` access, not `read` access.

This is true even if the workflow does something like run CI tests and does not write any code.