# GitHub Actions: Must have admin rights to trigger workflow_dispatch?

Tags: github, github-actions, github-api

Using the github API I am trying to manually start a workflow using:

```
  curl \
  -X POST \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \ 
  -H "Authorization: MY_TOKEN" \
  https://api.github.com/repos/djpr-data/djprdashdata/actions/workflows/refresh-data.yaml/dispatches
```

but I keep getting an authentication error:

```
{
  "message": "Must have admin rights to Repository.",
  "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/actions#create-a-workflow-dispatch-event"
}
```

This seems to be a similar issue to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70740116/getting-not-found-after-authenticating-when-trying-to-initiate-github-workflow). But my PAT token has all `admin` and `repo` scopes selected. I also have my user account setup as `admin` for the repository and I have added a workflow dispatch to the workflow yaml file.

```
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      tags:
        description:
          "run from cmdline"
```

I have been following the docs at https://docs.github.com/en/rest/actions/workflows#create-a-workflow-dispatch-event and have had no problems using the API to retrieve all previous workflow jobs. I have also tried the `runs` and `jobs` endpoints but get the same error. So I am now not sure what else I can do. Is there somewhere else I need to set permissions?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a poor error message to tell you that your request is not formed correctly. If you want to pass a PAT as a header, you need to prefix it with `token`, as described in the [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/actions/workflows#create-a-workflow-dispatch-event):

`-H "Authorization: token MY_TOKEN"`

Once that's resolved, however, you'll also get an error because you don't pass the required `ref` payload. Assuming your default branch is `main`, here's a correct curl command:

```bash
> export MY_TOKEN=gha_abcdef
> curl \
  -X POST \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \ 
  -H "Authorization: token $MY_TOKEN" \
  -d '{"ref": "main"}' \
  https://api.github.com/repos/djpr-data/djprdashdata/actions/workflows/refresh-data.yaml/dispatches
```

Comment: thanks @rethab, I had tried that before but got a malformed request error, and my other API queries that worked I had removed the 'token' before the `$MY_TOKEN`. But I added it back in and included the `-d '{"ref": "main"}'` and it is working perfectly. Thanks so much

Comment: the link you provided as "docs" shows using "Bearer" preceeding the token (not "token")